# PHP/SQL cannot get the value of a field name containing a forward slash

Tags: php, sql

I have a field named Role/Position but the problem is I cannot call it using this code:

```
$SQLposition = "select distinct `Role/Position` from document 
                 where `TypeID`='$row2->TypeID' and `AppID`='$id1' ";
$resultposition = mysql_query($SQLposition, $con);
while ($rowposition = mysql_fetch_object($resultposition)){
    echo $rowposition->Role/Position;
}
```

I get an error about dividing by zero. If I also use backticks, curly brackets, or a combination thereof, it still does not work. What should I use to call this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_object` like

```
while ($rowposition = mysql_fetch_array($resultposition)){
    echo $rowposition['Role/Position'];
}
```

And please follow the mysql rules while creating the fields.Look into this [**LINK**](http://justinsomnia.org/2003/04/essential-database-naming-conventions-and-style/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like:

```
echo $rowposition->{'Role/Position'};
```